# LEFT JOIN after Group By and HAVING

Tags: sql, group-by, teradata

I have a view cnst_prsn_nm . I want to check for records which share same cnst_mstr_id and same last name but differ on first names. So I did in Teradata SQL

```
SELECT  TOP 20 prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id  FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a
INNER JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_b
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = prsn_nm_b.cnst_mstr_id
GROUP BY prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm) = 1
WHERE prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm <> prsn_nm_b.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm
```

And then for those records' cnst_mstr_ids, I want to check another table cnst_mstr . 
Basically I want to check for where **left join IS NULL**

```
LEFT JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bzal_cnst_mstr mstr_new
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id
WHERE mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id IS NULL
```

So my query becomes essentially

```
SELECT  TOP 20 prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id  FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a
INNER JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_b
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = prsn_nm_b.cnst_mstr_id
GROUP BY prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm) = 1
WHERE prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm <> prsn_nm_b.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm
LEFT JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bzal_cnst_mstr mstr_new
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id
WHERE mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id IS NULL
```

But there are two WHERE Clauses . Also LEFT JOIN cannot be there directly after HAVING . How can I have a left join after Group By and HAVING Clause when there is Filter associated with the Grouping ?

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is clearly not MySQL.

Comment: Makes sense. But I hope this is general SQL related question , not any RDBMS Specific one.

Comment: TOP is product specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original query is not correct (`WHERE` goes before `GROUP BY`)  Let me assuming you mean this:

```
SELECT  TOP 20 prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a INNER JOIN
     arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_b
     ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = prsn_nm_b.cnst_mstr_id
WHERE prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm <> prsn_nm_b.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm
GROUP BY prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm) = 1;
```

A non-matching left join is equivalent to using `NOT EXISTS`, so you can do:

```
SELECT TOP 20 prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a INNER JOIN
     arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_b
     ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = prsn_nm_b.cnst_mstr_id
WHERE prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm <> prsn_nm_b.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm
GROUP BY prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm) = 1 AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                   FROM arc_mdm_vws.bzal_cnst_mstr mstr_new
                   WHERE prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id
                  );
```

Answer (score 3):

The clauses in a SQL statement always come in a specific order. First `SELECT`, then `FROM`, then `JOIN`s, then `WHERE`, then `GROUP BY`, then `HAVING`. You cannot deviate from that order, and do not need (and cannot have) a second `WHERE` clause. Make your one and only `WHERE` clause include ***all*** the condition you need.

```
SELECT  TOP 20 prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id  
FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a
INNER JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_b
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = prsn_nm_b.cnst_mstr_id
LEFT JOIN arc_mdm_vws.bzal_cnst_mstr mstr_new
    ON prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id = mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id
WHERE prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm <> prsn_nm_b.bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm
  AND mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id IS NULL
GROUP BY prsn_nm_a.cnst_mstr_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT prsn_nm_a.bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You task can be written like this without self-join:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT TOP 20 -- why TOP?
      cnst_mstr_id, bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm
   FROM arc_mdm_vws.bz_cnst_prsn_nm prsn_nm_a
   GROUP BY cnst_mstr_id, bz_cnst_prsn_last_nm      -- same customer & name
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT bz_cnst_prsn_first_nm) > 1 -- different first_names
 ) AS prsn_nm
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (
   SELECT * 
   FROM arc_mdm_vws.bzal_cnst_mstr mstr_new
   WHERE prsn_nm.cnst_mstr_id = mstr_new.new_cnst_mstr_id
 )
```

Depending on the existing indexes this might be faster than a self-join.

And as Gordon already mentioned, `LEFT JOIN ... IS NULL` is the same as `NOT EXISTS` and in Teradata the latter is usually more efficient.